# Delegate via tezos-client with an encrypted key implicit account?

Tags: tezos-client, delegating

Since babylon now implicit accounts can delegate. I'm using an implicit account to make the payments to my delegators, the account key is encrypted, the unencrypted key hasn't been exposed and i would like it to stay that way. I would like to delegate that account to myself via tezos-client since the alias is already there.

I have no idea what command to use. Please any help?

Comment: Could the `tezos-client set delegate for <src> to <mgr>` command help?

Comment: Yep, i just had to write this command 

./tezos-client set delegate for (aliasofdelegator) to (aliasofdelegate)

Both were tz1 accounts.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following command, as per the [command-line interface](http://tezos.gitlab.io/api/cli-commands.html):

```
tezos-client set delegate for <aliasofdelegator> to <aliasofdelegate>
```